# IF_ELSE statement not working as expected

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am trying to create a new variable based off a conditional evaluation of a number of other variables. I am using some nested "if_else" statements, but only part of the conditional statement is evaluating as I want it to.

Here is the dput for some sample data:

```
structure(list(`Cultivation` = c("No", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes"), 
`Processing` = c("No", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"Yes"), `Federal Sales` = c("No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes"), `Cultivation 
Type` = c(NA, 
NA, "Standard", "Standard", NA, "Micro", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Nursery", 
"Standard"), `Processing Type` = c(NA, NA, "Standard", 
"Standard", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Standard"), `Type` = c(NA, 
NA, "Standard", "Standard", NA, "Micro", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"Standard")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
DF.2 <- DF.1 %>%
  dplyr::mutate("Type" = if_else(str_detect(tolower(`Cultivation Type`), 
"micro") |

str_detect(tolower(`Processing Type`), "micro"), "Micro",

if_else(str_detect(tolower(`Cultivation Type`), "standard") |

str_detect(tolower(`Processing Type`), "standard"), "Standard",

if_else(str_detect(tolower(`Cultivation Type`), "nursery"), 
"Nursery","Other"))))
```

The first two conditions are being met and I get a type variable of either "standard" or "micro", but "nursery" and "other" do not evaluate and I get "NA".

Comment: There are `NA` in that column and that needs to be taken care of

Comment: If there are many values to replace, an option would be a key/val dataset and then do a fuzzyjoin

Comment: I thought NA's might be the cause of my issues. Do you know why row 6 evaulates properly for Micro though since one of the columns also contains an "NA"? Also, is there a way to deal with the NA's within the nested if_else statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best to use `case_when` in your case instead of `if_else`. Here all `NA` have resulted in `Other`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

DF.2 <- DF.1 %>%
  mutate("Type" = case_when(
    str_detect(tolower(`Cultivation Type`),"micro") | str_detect(tolower(`Processing Type`), "micro") ~ "Micro",
    str_detect(tolower(`Cultivation Type`), "standard") | str_detect(tolower(`Processing Type`), "standard") ~ "Standard",
    str_detect(tolower(`Cultivation Type`), "nursery") ~ "Nursery",
    TRUE ~ "Other")
  )
```

Output:

```
> DF.2
# A tibble: 12 x 6
   Cultivation Processing `Federal Sales` `Cultivation Type` `Processing Type` Type    
   <chr>       <chr>      <chr>           <chr>              <chr>             <chr>   
 1 No          No         No              NA                 NA                Other   
 2 No          No         No              NA                 NA                Other   
 3 Yes         Yes        Yes             Standard           Standard          Standard
 4 Yes         Yes        Yes             Standard           Standard          Standard
 5 No          No         Yes             NA                 NA                Other   
 6 Yes         No         Yes             Micro              NA                Micro   
 7 No          No         No              NA                 NA                Other   
 8 No          No         No              NA                 NA                Other   
 9 No          No         No              NA                 NA                Other   
10 No          No         No              NA                 NA                Other   
11 Yes         No         Yes             Nursery            NA                Nursery 
12 Yes         Yes        Yes             Standard           Standard          Standard
>
```

Comment: This is great. I have never used case_when but it looks like it does exactly what I need. WIll look into the documentation a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of help. It is indeed very handy for multiple case conversions!

Answer (score 0):

We need to make some changes in the code to return only `TRUE/FALSE` as the `NA` elements return only `NA` and this can result in the issue

```
library(dplyr)
DF.1 %>%
  dplyr::mutate("Type" = if_else((str_detect(tolower(`Cultivation Type`), "micro") | str_detect(tolower(`Processing Type`), "micro")) & !(is.na(`Cultivation Type`) |  is.na(`Processing Type`)), "Micro",

     if_else((str_detect(tolower(`Cultivation Type`), "standard") | str_detect(tolower(`Processing Type`), "standard")) & !(is.na(`Cultivation Type`) | is.na(`Processing Type`)), "Standard",

     if_else(str_detect(tolower(`Cultivation Type`), "nursery") & !is.na(`Cultivation Type`),  "Nursery","Other"))))
# A tibble: 12 x 6
#   Cultivation Processing `Federal Sales` `Cultivation Type` `Processing Type` Type    
#   <chr>       <chr>      <chr>           <chr>              <chr>             <chr>   
# 1 No          No         No              <NA>               <NA>              Other   
# 2 No          No         No              <NA>               <NA>              Other   
# 3 Yes         Yes        Yes             Standard           Standard          Standard
# 4 Yes         Yes        Yes             Standard           Standard          Standard
# 5 No          No         Yes             <NA>               <NA>              Other   
# 6 Yes         No         Yes             Micro              <NA>              Other   
# 7 No          No         No              <NA>               <NA>              Other   
# 8 No          No         No              <NA>               <NA>              Other   
# 9 No          No         No              <NA>               <NA>              Other   
#10 No          No         No              <NA>               <NA>              Other   
#11 Yes         No         Yes             Nursery            <NA>              Nursery 
#12 Yes         Yes        Yes             Standard           Standard          Standard
```

---

Or if we need to use the same code as in OP's post, just replace the `NA` in the columns 'Type' before and change the value replaced to NA after the transformations

```
DF.1 %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with('Type')), replace_na, 'new') %>% 
   dplyr::mutate("Type" = if_else(str_detect(tolower(`Cultivation Type`), 
 "micro") |

 str_detect(tolower(`Processing Type`), "micro"), "Micro",

 if_else(str_detect(tolower(`Cultivation Type`), "standard") |

 str_detect(tolower(`Processing Type`), "standard"), "Standard",

 if_else(str_detect(tolower(`Cultivation Type`), "nursery"), 
 "Nursery","Other")))) %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(ends_with('Type')), na_if, 'new')
```

---

If we are interested in other easier options, another option is to create a key/val dataset and then do a fuzzyjoin